# Animate LinearLayout when keyboard goes up/down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView ... />

            <EditText ... />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView ... />

            <EditText ... />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to fade out the `ImageView` and move the second (inner) `LinearLayout` up (near the top of the screen) when the keyboard comes up and then do the opposite when the keyboard goes back down.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use **TranslateAnimation** class to animate your view.

```
Animation slide = new TranslateAnimation(fromX,toX,fromY,toY);
slide.setDuration(300);//here you can set your own duration of animation in ms.
yourView.startAnimation(slide);
```

You can also override some callbacks.

```
slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

There is no direct way of finding out whether android softkey pad is opne or not . But you can do a work around and calculate the size diff between your activity's view root and the window size. There are many ways to do it, one way that i found was this:

```
    final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            ... do something here
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: How do I check if the keyboard is up/down?